# Django custom model field to_python gets called multiple times in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Following is the custom field I am creating:

```
class TransactionStateField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.CharField)):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        super(TransactionStateField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value:
            print value.__class__, 11111111111
            kls = import_by_path(value)
            return kls()
        return None

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value:
            return fullname(value)
        return None
```

This is the model:

```
class AbstractTransaction(models.Model):
    processed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    cancelled_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def process(self):
        raise NotImplemented()


class Transaction(AbstractTransaction):
    CURRENCIES = (('NZD', 'New Zealand Dollars'), ('EUR', 'Euro'))
    currency = models.CharField(choices=CURRENCIES, max_length=25)
    user_goid = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    order_goid = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    billingtoken = models.ForeignKey('BillingToken', null=True, blank=True)
    state = TransactionStateField(default='project.apps.transactions.states.NewTransaction')

    def process(self):
        self.state.process(self)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} ${}".format(self.currency, self.amount)
```

And this is the admin:

```
class SubTransactionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SubTransaction
    extra = 0


class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SubTransactionInline]

admin.site.register(Transaction, TransactionAdmin)
```

When I create the transaction record (no sub transactions in inline) in admin, `to_python` method gets called 3 times with different value types

```
<type 'unicode'> 11111111111
<type 'unicode'> 11111111111
<class 'project.apps.transactions.states.NewTransaction'> 11111111111
```

And you see the last one is a different type which is causing trouble.

But if I create the record in `python manage.py shell` it only gets called once:

```
>>> t = Transaction.objects.create(amount=11111, currency='NZD')
<type 'unicode'> 11111111111
```